# How to instantiate value of unknown type in Go?

Tags: go, reflection

I develop some server in golang. I try to create some wrapper-function, which can helps me in future.

What I have:

1) I had some DTO structs, for example:

```
type Request struct {
    Field1   string `json:"field1"`
    Field2   string `json:"field2"`
}

type Response struct {
    Field1   string `json:"field1"`
    Field2   string `json:"field2"`
    Field3   string `json:"field3"`
}
```

2) I had some functions, in controller layer, which (by conventions) receives 1 argument (pointer to struct) and returns 1 result (pointer to struct), for example:

```
func SomeHandler(request *Request) *Response{
    ...do something
    return &Response{"first","second","third"}
}
```

What I need:

I need to write wrapper function which receives as argument:

1. pointer to 'controller' function
2. http.ResponseWriter
3. *http.Request

This wrapper function must:

1. Determine type of argument of 'controller' function
2. Determine type of result of 'controller' function
3. Instantiate and fill argument value from Body of *http.Request (decode from json)
4. Call controller Function with instantiated on previous step argument
5. Write results of previous step into http.ResponseWriter (encoded as json)

Wrapper must work correct with any types of 'controller' functions - signatures of this functions is different (different argument type, different result type)

Can anybody help me with implementing of this wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is a bit weird but [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) can provide all the info you need.

```
func myFunction(a string, b int32) error {
    return nil
}

func myWrapper(mystery interface{}) {
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(mystery)

    // Check typ.Kind before playing with In(i);
    for i := 0; i < typ.NumIn(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Param %d: %v\n", i, typ.In(i))
    }
    for i := 0; i < typ.NumOut(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("Result %d: %v\n", i, typ.Out(i))
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
Param 0: string
Param 1: int32
Result 0: error
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You wrote that things that I do is a bit wired, maybe you're right, I'm newbie in golang. So what is go-way to solve problem? I don't want to write the similar code many times, but in a lot of 'controller' functions I need to do same things: decode input from json to my models (structs), encode data from my objects to json and write it to output, but I don't understand howto do it in go-way, can you help me?

Comment: @YuriiVasilchuk I don't understand your exact use case. I think you could change your approach to have a single function that does the encoding and decoding (go's Marshal/Unmarshal are quite generic: they take interface{}s so you can pass anything). All this function needs to know is the source/destination types and I think you "know" that from the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
func wrapper(ctlr interface{}, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {

    tpe := reflect.TypeOf(ctlr)
    if tpe.Kind() != reflect.Func || tpe.NumIn() != 1 || tpe.NumOut() != 1 {
        // TODO: handle wrong ctlr type
    }

    // 1. Determine type of argument of 'controller' function
    argt := tpe.In(0)

    // 2. Determine type of result of 'controller' function
    // rest := tpe.Out(0) // commented out since it's useless

    // 3. Instantiate and fill argument value from Body of *http.Request (decode from json)
    arg := reflect.Zero(argt)
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&arg)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle err
    }

    // 4. Call controller Function with instantiated on previous step argument
    resv := reflect.ValueOf(ctlr).Call([]reflect.Value{arg})[0]

    // 5. Write results of previous step into http.ResponseWriter (encoded as json)
    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resv.Interface())
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note that the second step is unnecessary.